# Can Present Perfect with a time period tell about an action that stopped in the past

Tags: perfect-aspect

> I **spent** *20 years* in the software industry where...

As I was taught, it implies that the talker doesn't work in this software industry now. Otherwise he would have said "I **have spent** 20 years..."

My question is why you can't use *Present Perfect* with *a time period* to bring a fact to the present existence, the fact about some action that **stopped in the past**?

I can say "I have worked in this industry"—it may mean that it is a fact that I spent some time in that industry before. But with a specified time period I just *add the time prolongation* to that fact. It is like the government issues a law that anybody who spent in some industry 20 years, receives a compensation. And you say—"I *have spent* 20 years there. Give me my money."

Comment: I would say that your example sentence would imply that there is at least a possibility that the person would return to the industry. If there is no such possibility, it would make more sense to say "I spent 20 years there."

Comment: @Daniel: I don't see how *any* verb form can have implications for the likelihood of ***returning*** to, or ***resuming*** the activity, except insofar as you can't "return" if you never left it (and some forms do imply you're *still* doing whatever it is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As OP has correctly understood, *I worked 20 years in the software industry* **strongly** implies that you no longer work in that industry.

But that doesn't mean *I have worked 20 years in the software industry* strongly implies that you *still* work in that industry. Perhaps you do, perhaps you don't. Without further context, it's meaningless to discuss whether there's any "weak implication").

If you want to **strongly** imply you're still doing it, use *I **have been working** in the industry for 20 years.*

Comment: I hear for the first time that *Perfect Continuous* gives a stronger implication of the fact that the talker is still  doing the action. Look at this example: "They *fired me* this morning. My god, I *have been working* in the company for 20 years. What am I going to do now?"

Comment: @Graduate: haha - in that particular case obviously the speaker *no longer works for the company* (having just been fired). So it's a bad example to give people who are trying to learn how tenses work in English, because most native speakers probably wouldn't have a strong opinion about whether to use Simple Past *(worked)*, Present Perfect *(have worked)*, or Present Perfect Continuous *(have been working)*. I think probably the most important thing to take on board is that no native speaker would *ever* say *"?I **have been spending** 20 years there. Give me my money."*

Comment: Is the sentence "I **have spent** 20 years in this industry" *grammatically correct* if I stopped working in the industry 10 years ago? Is it *ambigous*?

Comment: @Graduate: Your exact example is not helpful here, because the specific verb *spend* isn't used in quite the same way as *work*. It's extremely unlikely anyone would say "I have spent 20 years here" unless they were still there (or *very recently* left). But "I have spent several summers working abroad" is a perfectly credible utterance, which says nothing about whether you're still doing this, or likely to do it again in the future.

Comment: If I change the verb to *worked*, will it change your opinion? ("I *have worked* 20 years in this industry.") I want to catch an instance of this usage for **any verb**, that is legitimate given that you **stopped doing** it many years ago.

Comment: @Graduate: The first two paragraphs in my answer give my opinion regarding the verb *to work* in the context of your original question. In general, Simple Past implies something you *did*, but are *no longer doing*. Present Perfect Continuous almost always implies *you did it in the past, and you're **still** doing it now*. Present Perfect implies what you did in the past is *still relevant* - possibly because you're still doing it, possibly because the fact that you once did it is important to the current circumstances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I remember correctly, my English textbooks taught me that you often use Present Perfect Continuous for actions that _have finished recently_ but are _still relevant_. "Why are you breathing so hard?" - "I've been running" (=just stopped running). "Why are your hands so dirty?" - "I've been working in the garden." (=just finished working)

Comment: @stillenat: My mistake - you're quite right that Present Perfect Continuous is *also* used in contexts where you've ***only just stopped*** doing something. The "ordinary" Present Perfect can refer to events long ago, but the "continuous" version has to be *recent*. *"I feel a bit queasy because I **have been getting** full vaccination jabs this week ready for our holiday. But my wife is fine - because she **has had** the jabs before, she's only been having 'boosters' that don't make you feel sick"*.